# Limit as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ tend to 1, indeterminate form

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

I have the equation $F=\cfrac{\beta (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta) e^{\lambda t}}{\alpha (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta) e^{\lambda t}}.$

such that $\lambda = \beta - \alpha$

I need to take the limit as $\alpha$ and $\beta$ tend to 1. Clearly, just trying to see what $F$ is at the limit gives $\frac{0}{0}$.

I have tried using L'Hopital's rule doing a partial derivative w.r.t $\alpha$ and this yields $\frac{st-t+s}{st-t+1}$ but I'm not sure if I can use L'hopital like this or if this a correct answer for what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The limit has two possibilities.

Case 1 : $\lambda t\neq 0$

In this case, we must have

$\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(1,1)} \cfrac{\beta (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta) e^{\lambda t}}{\alpha (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta) e^{\lambda t}}$

$= \cfrac{(s-1)-(s-1) e^{\lambda t}}{(s-1)-(s-1) e^{\lambda t}}$

$= \cfrac{(s-1)(1- e^{\lambda t})}{(s-1)(1-e^{\lambda t})}$

$=1 $         (as $e^{\lambda t} \neq 1$)

Case 2 : $\lambda t=0$

In this case, we get

$\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(1,1)} \cfrac{\beta (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta) e^{\lambda t}}{\alpha (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta) e^{\lambda t}}$

$=\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(1,1)} \cfrac{\beta (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta)}{\alpha (s-1)-(\alpha s-\beta)}$

$=\lim_{(\alpha,\beta)\to(1,1)} \cfrac{(\beta -\alpha) s}{(\beta -\alpha)}$

$=s$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm really sorry but I forgot to add that lambda is beta - alpha. I think this changes the solution?

Comment: Yes, It will change the solution.